# chart.js: alternating background-color for ticks

Tags: chart.js

I want to have alternating background-colors in a bar chart with chart.js. There is this old, but deprecated plugin, which did exaclty what I wanted [here](https://github.com/datavisyn/chartjs-plugin-barchart-background)

The first sample picture on the bottom of the repo is what I need.
Haven't found anything new, nor a way without a plugin. Can anyone explain me how to achive the alternating bg, in the current version of chart.js (3.7.0)?

thx alot!

Comment: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/samples/bar/vertical.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the [chartjs-plugin-annotation](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation) library as shown in the runnable script below.

> Detailed information about **Box Annotations** can be found [here](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/latest/guide/types/box.html)

```js
const labels = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'];

new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Dataset 1',
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        data: [95, 70, 55, -88, -64, 34, -55]
      },
      {
        label: 'Dataset 2',
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        data: [81, 58, 30, -91, -74, 20, -40]
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      annotation: {
        annotations: labels
          .map((l, i) => ({
            drawTime: 'beforeDatasetsDraw',
            type: 'box',
            xScaleID: 'x',
            yScaleID: 'y',
            xMin: i - 0.5,
            xMax: i + 0.5,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.4)',
            borderWidth: 1
          }))
          .filter((l, i) => !(i % 2))
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/1.2.2/chartjs-plugin-annotation.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" width="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you! that's what I was searching and failed :-(